# How can I use jQuery to move an <option> to be the second element?

Tags: jquery

How can I use jQuery to move a specific `<option>` to be the second option?

```
<select class="comestibles">
 <option>apple</option>
 <option>banana</option>
 <option>cantaloupe</option>
 <option>date</option>
 <option>eggplant</option>
 <option>fig</option>
</select>

<select class="comestibles">
 <option>apple</option>
 <option>banana</option>
 <option>cantaloupe</option>
 <option>date</option>
 <option>eggplant</option>
 <option>fig</option>
</select>
```

This code will make `eggplant` the first option... close but no cigar.

```
jQuery('select.comestibles').each(function(){
  $('option[value=eggplant]',this).prependTo(this);
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming there's only one select element...

```
jQuery('option[value=eggplant]').insertAfter('option:first-child')
```

I also assume that you actually have `value` attributes on your elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/wNmLF/

---

The code in the question changed. Now it would be...

```
jQuery('select.comestibles option[value=eggplant]').insertAfter('select.comestibles option:first-child')
```

---

For the most recent change...

```
jQuery('select.comestibles').each(function(){
    var opts = $(this).children();
    opts.filter('[value=eggplant]').insertAfter(opts.first())
});
```

Comment: sorry, i had to change it again. i need to do it in an `.each()` loop. also jQuery will use the value between `>` and `<` if no `value` attribute is specified.

Comment: @cwd: I updated. And you can't rely on jQuery using the text content in lieu of the value attribute. It will work for a `filter`, but not necessarily for DOM selection. In Chrome, [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/wNmLF/2/) will show 1 instead of 2 matched elements.

Comment: thanks. i've accepted. never tested with mixed <option> value definitions. +1 - thanks for sharing.