# Copy inner html of one select element and paste it in a new, dynamically, created select element

Tags: jquery, html, select

When the page first loads I have a select element populated with multiple option nested elements.

Next to it is an "ADD" button which dynamically adds a new select element with a button "ADD" next to it.

I was wondering how can I copy the option elements from the first select element into every subsequent dynamically created select element with jQuery?

Comment: what is the problem? you have to do exactly what you said: copy it, change it's id, and append it to the bottom...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use jQuery to move an <option> to be the second element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640899/how-can-i-use-jquery-to-move-an-option-to-be-the-second-element)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understood you correct you want to copy the options from one select to other(s)? If so this should work (untested):

```
(function($) {
    $('a').click(function() {
        var $options = $('.theSelect option').clone();
        $('.otherSelects').append($options);

        $newSelect = $('<select></select>').append($options);

        $('body').append($newSelect);

        return false;
    });
})(jQuery);​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PeeHaa/twffL/1/

Comment: clone() is the correct way to go. Will mark your answer as the correct one to my question in 6 minutes. +1

Comment: HMM.. remember that I'm dynamically creating the second element.. it is not static :/ will this code work?

Comment: You want to dynamically add the complete new select? Or is there another problem so I can update my answer / demo?

Comment: yes I want to dynamically create a new select element. It does not exist. I'm creating it using jquery ('<div><select><option> ... )

Answer (score 3):

Create a div  where your select resides. Assign div a class.

```
<div class = "select_class">
<select>
<option>blah</option>
<select>    
<div/>
```

and Now

```
var my_var = $('.select_class').html();
```

Now create a new div and assign the my_var to it

```
$('#new_div').html(my_var);
```

Done
This is only basic concept

Answer (score 0):

Put the content that you want to copy in a div with id olddiv and also create a new div with id newdiv where you want to copy the contents to. Then on onclick of add button in olddiv, just write the following code:

```
$("#addbutton").click(function()
{
  $("#newdiv").html($("#olddiv").html());
});
```

Comment: I need to dynamically create the seocnd div.. it does not exist.